# Read DataTable using a foreach and put the values into DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#

**Here my DataTable**
public DataTable GetValues()

```
    dt.Columns.Add("num");
    dt.Columns.Add("nam");
    dt.Columns.Add("amt");

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = 1;
    row[1] = "cha";
    row[2] = 20;

    row2[0] = 2;
    row2[1] = "nip";
    row2[2] = 22;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    dt.Rows.Add(row2);
    return dt;
```

**I have created three columns in form load event**

```
private void testWin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Number", "Number");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Amount", "Amount");
```

I'm reading DataTable like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = _testClass.GetValues();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string v = row["num"].ToString();
        string v1 = row["nam"].ToString();
        string v2 = row["amt"].ToString();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell1 = gridRow.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCell;
            DataGridViewCell cell2 = gridRow.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCell;
            DataGridViewCell cell3 = gridRow.Cells[2] as DataGridViewCell;

            cell1.Value = v;
            cell2.Value = v1;
            cell3.Value = v2;
        }
    }
```

**But it's only display the last value in DataGridView
What is my problem**

Thank you

Comment: What youre doing in the loop for your datagridview is just changing the same row over and over again. You dont need a loop for datagridview. Instead of that just use `dataGridView1.Rows.Add()` function

Answer (score 1):

try this code hope it will help

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    //string v = row["num"].ToString();
    //string v1 = row["nam"].ToString();
    //string v2 = row["amt"].ToString();

    //foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
    //{
        //DataGridViewCell cell1 = gridRow.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCell;
        //DataGridViewCell cell2 = gridRow.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCell;
        //DataGridViewCell cell3 = gridRow.Cells[2] as DataGridViewCell;

        //cell1.Value = v;
        //cell2.Value = v1;
        //cell3.Value = v2;
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

dt is the datatable.